# Why are there groups in Islam if it is against Allah's word

Tags: quran, islamic-philosophy

In surah Ar-roem, ayat 32 one can read the following:

*Don't be part of those who have divided their religion and become sects, every faction rejoicing in what it has*

So why are there groups in islam, like sunni, shi'a, kharijte, sufi, ahmadija and so on since this ayat clearly shows we can't divide our religion into subdivisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like asking why do many Muslims drink alcohol or are involved in gambling or deal with riba when it’s forbidden in the Qur’an.

The Ummah being divided into sects is something our Prophet Muhammad (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) have said that will happen:

> The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) also described
>   them in the following terms: “My ummah will split into seventy-three
>   sects, all of whom will be in Hell except one group.” They said: Who
>   are they, O Messenger of Allaah? He said: “(Those who follow) that
>   which I and my companions follow.” This is mentioned in the hadeeth of
>   ‘Abd-Allaah ibn ‘Amr which was recorded and classed as hasan by
>   al-Tirmidhi (2641). It was also classed as hasan by al-‘Iraaqi in
>   Ahkaam al-Qur’aan (3/432), al-‘Iraaqi in Takhreej al-Ihya’ (3/284) and
>   al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.